# PowerShell issue when adding a new user in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

I'm encountering an issue in a script I've written in Powershell for the creation of a user i, Active Directory. My problem occurs when calling the "New-ADUser"'s cmdlet. I created a variable in which I embedded the "OU" and another one for the security group. When I hard-code the "OU" (eg.: $OU = 'OU=TESTS,OU=RDS,DC=dism,DC=local')  and the security group (eg.: $MembreDuGroupe = "IffendicTest"), everything works fine. But as soon as I replace this information by variables that retrieve them from the lists, an issue soon comes out. I've tried using double quotes, and later on single quotes. But in all cases, the issue  is that an invalid argument has been used within the New-ADUser instruction. For the moment, the error occurs the "New-ADUser" asks for the Path's parameter ("OU"). But I suppose that the same issue will occur after that. I have pasted my script in order to make you see and definitively understand my error. I have created procedures to dynamically build "OUs" and security groups so that the users won't have to act directly in the Active Directory.
Any idea would be welcome (Sorry, the comments are written in french. But I can translate if necessary... ).

PowerShell Code:

```
# Ne surtout pas oublier d'exécuter la commande ci-dessous en mode administrateur
# lorsque l'on a un message du genre "Impossible de charger le fichier "ScriptPowerShell.ps1"
# Commande à exécuter -> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

# Import du module de l'AD pour l'exécution de AD cmdlets
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Bibliothèques pour la création de formulaire
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# Chargement de l'assemblage permettant d'afficher 1 MessageBox
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

# Saisie des informations générales de l'utilisateur
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

Clear-Host

# On définit le "UPN"
$UPN = "dism.local"

# # Encapsulation en mémoire des données de l'utilisateur dans les
# # variables cortrespondantes

$msgID            = "Saisissez l'identifiant de l'utilisateur : "

$identifiant      = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msgID,"Identifiant") #,         $titreID)

if (Get-ADUser -F { SamAccountName -eq $identifiant }) 
{   
    # Si l'utilisateur existe, afficher un message d'alerte et mettre fin au script
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Le compte d'utilisateur $identifiant existe déjà dans l'AD.","Oups ! Un doublon...")
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Fin du script...","Fin du processus")
    Exit
}

# Création du formulaire de stockage des groupes de sécurité de l'AD
$frmGRP                    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$frmGRP.Text               = 'Selection de groupes'
$frmGRP.Size               = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,500)
$frmGRP.StartPosition      = 'CenterScreen'

$OKButton                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,430)
$OKButton.Size             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text             = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult     = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

$frmGRP.AcceptButton       = $OKButton
$frmGRP.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,430)
$CancelButton.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text         = 'Abandonner'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$frmGRP.CancelButton       = $CancelButton
$frmGRP.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$lblGRP                    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblGRP.Location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$lblGRP.Size               = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20) # New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$lblGRP.Text               = 'Veuillez selectionner un ou plusieurs groupes...'
$frmGRP.Controls.Add($lblGRP)

$lstbGRP                   = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$lstbGRP.Location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$lstbGRP.Size              = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)

# Activation de la sélection multiples de groupes de sécurité
$lstbGRP.SelectionMode     = 'MultiExtended'

# Nom du fichier .csv des groupes de sécurité de l'AD
$fichierGRP = ".\ExportedGRP.csv"

if (Test-Path $fichierGRP)
{
  Remove-Item $fichierGRP
}

# Création dynamique de la liste des groupes de sécurité
Get-ADGroup -Filter '*' | Where-Object{ $_.objectclass -eq 'Group' } `
                        | Select-Object name `
                        | Sort-Object name `
                        | Export-Csv -encoding utf8 -Path $fichierGRP

(Get-Content $fichierGRP) -Replace '"', '' | Set-Content $fichierGRP

Get-Content $fichierGRP | ForEach-Object {[void] $lstbGRP.Items.Add($_)}

# Taille du champs d'affichage de la liste des groupes de sécurité
$lstbGRP.Height = 390
$frmGRP.Controls.Add($lstbGRP)
$frmGRP.Topmost = $true

# Affichage du formulaire des groupes de sécurité
$resultGRP = $frmGRP.ShowDialog()

# Sélection d'un groupe de sécurité pour l'utilisateur
if ($resultGRP -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $MembreDuGroupe = $lstbGRP.SelectedItems
    # Lignes ci-dessous à supprimer, par la suite.
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Groupe de sécurité sélectionné = $MembreDuGroupe","Contrôle sélection Groupe de sécurité")
}
else
{
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Fin du script...","Fin du processus")
    Exit
}

# Création du formulaires des OU
$frmOU                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$frmOU.Text                = 'Uniés Organisationnelles'
$frmOU.Size                = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,210)
$frmOU.StartPosition       = 'CenterScreen'

$lblOU                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblOU.Location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$lblOU.Size                = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$lblOU.Text                = 'Veuillez selectionner une ou plusieurs OU...'
$frmOU.Controls.Add($lblOU)

$lstbOU                    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$lstbOU.Location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$lstbOU.Size               = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)
#$lstbOU.SelectionMode      = 'MultiExtended'

$btnOU_OK                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOU_OK.Location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,140)
$btnOU_OK.Size             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$btnOU_OK.Text             = 'OK'
$btnOU_OK.DialogResult     = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

$btnOU_Cancel              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOU_Cancel.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,140)
$btnOU_Cancel.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$btnOU_Cancel.Text         = 'Abandonner'
$btnOU_Cancel.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$frmOU.CancelButton        = $btnOU_Cancel
$frmOU.Controls.Add($btnOU_Cancel)

$frmOU.AcceptButton        = $btnOU_OK
$frmOU.Controls.Add($btnOU_OK)

# Nom du fichier des OU au format .csv
$fichierOU = ".\ExportedOUs.csv"

# Remise à neuf du fichier -> Suppression du fichier, s'il existe
if (Test-Path $fichierOU) 
{
  Remove-Item $fichierOU
}

# Creation d'un fichier CSV pour stocker les OU
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * `
                        -Properties Name | Sort-Object Name `
                                         | Select-Object -Property DistinguishedName `
                                         | Export-Csv -encoding utf8 -Path $fichierOU

(Get-Content $fichierOU) -Replace '"', "'" | Set-Content $fichierOU

Get-Content $fichierOU | ForEach-Object {[void] $lstbOU.Items.Add($_)}

# Taille du champs d'affichage de la liste
$lstbOU.Height = 100
$frmOU.Controls.Add($lstbOU)
$frmOU.Topmost = $true

$resultOU = $frmOU.ShowDialog()

# Sélection d'un OU pour l'utilisateur
if ($resultOU -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $OU = $lstbOU.SelectedItems
    # Ligne ci-dessous à supprimer, par la suite.
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("OU sélectionnée = $OU","Contrôle sélection OU")
}
else
{
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Fin du script...","Fin du processus")
    Exit
}

# Enregistrement des données
try
{
    New-ADUser -Name $identifiant -Path $OU # 'OU=TESTS,OU=RDS,DC=dism,DC=local'
        -Path $OU
        -SamAccountName $identifiant `
        
    # #Affecter l'utilisateur à un groupe
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $MembreDuGroupe -Members  $identifiant #'IffendicTest' 

    # A la création de l'utilisateur, afficher un message d'information
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("L'utilisateur $identifiant a été créé avec succès.","Création d'un utilisateur")
}
Catch
{
    # Affichage du message d'erreur
    # Récupération et affichage du message d'erreur dans son intégralité
    $formatstring = "{0} : {1}`n{2}`n" +
            "    + CategoryInfo          : {3}`n" +
            "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : {4}`n"
    $fields = $_.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name,
                $_.ErrorDetails.Message,
                $_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage,
                $_.CategoryInfo.ToString(),
                $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId

    # Pour afficher le message d'erreur dale la fenêtre PowerShell ISE
    # Supprimer le '#' avec la cmdlets ci-dessous : '$formatstring -f $fields'
    # $formatstring -f $fields

    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Une erreur est survenue lors de la création de l'utilisateur " + $identifiant + " " + $fields,"Oups ! Erreur lors du processus")
}

# Fin des traitements...
$msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Fin de traitements...","Fin du processus")
```

Comment: You should stop destroying your CSV files by opening them with Get-Content and removing all the quotes characters (or even worse, replacing them with single-qoutes). Especially when dealing with OU distinguished names, the quotes around these fields are vital

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is happening because the `$OU` variable doesn't contain a string, which is what the `New-ADUser` cmdlet will be expecting for its `-Path` parameter.

Debugging your script shows that `$OU` is of type `SelectedObjectCollection`:

[image: OU Type]

Your `$lstbOU` ListBox is configured in single selection mode, however when you retrieve the selected OU, you're asking for a collection of items to be returned.

Change this line from:

```
$OU = $lstbOU.SelectedItems
```

to:

```
$OU = $lstbOU.SelectedItem
```

*Note we're now using `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedItems`*

Hopefully that should do the trick?

**Edit - Trim OU variable**

After running the script in its entirety I ran into the same issue as you even after changing to `SelectedItem`.

It appears that the `New-ADUser` cmdlet doesn't like the apostrophes surrounding the OU returned from `SelectItem`, so again we'll need to change:

```
$OU = $lstbOU.SelectedItem
```

to:

```
$OU = ([string]$lstbOU.SelectedItem).Trim("'")
```

This will remove the apostrophes surrounding the string.

Comment: Hi NiMux,
Thanks for you answer. I did try your advice but I still got the same issue. Anyhow, you're right helping me realize that I'm suppose to use the following command:

Comment: Hi NiMux,
Thanks for you answer. I did try your advice but I still got the same issue. Anyhow, you're right helping me realize that I'm suppose to use the following command:
$OU = $lstbOU.SelectedItem. 
I even tried : $OU = $lstbOU.SelectedItem.ToString()
And still, the issue remains.

I'll keepon trying to debug thet script. If you hauve some other ideas, they'll all be welcomed.

Maybe, you should try my script and look deeper inside of it...

Hoping to read you soon.

Comment: I've run through your script again and found that the `New-ADUser` cmdlet doesn't like the apostrophes surrounding the OU returned from the list box. See the update to my answer for the change. After this has been done, you'll also run into another issue with adding groups: `Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot convert 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox+SelectedObjectCollection' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required by parameter 
'Identity'`. Looks like you'll need to loop through the desired groups and add them as `Add-ADGroupMember` only supports 1 group at a time

Comment: Hi NiMux,
You're idea of using 
$OU = $lstbOU.SelectedItem
Really helped ! That really did the trick, and thank you so much !!! Sorry, but I've been off for a couple of weeks, but I'm OK now.
Now that your trick helped, I'll right now end this post.
Take good care of you and your relatives !
Moumouni

Answer (score 0):

Finaly, Thanks to @NiMux, here's the solution that worked for me:

```
# Ne surtout pas oublier d'exécuter la commande ci-dessous en mode administrateur
# lorsque l'on a un message du genre "Impossible de charger le fichier "ScriptPowerShell.ps1"
# Commande à exécuter -> Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

# Import du module de l'AD pour l'exécution de AD cmdlets
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Bibliothèques pour la création de formulaire
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# Chargement de l'assemblage permettant d'afficher 1 MessageBox
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

# Saisie des informations générales de l'utilisateur
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')

Clear-Host

# On définit le "UPN"
$UPN = "dism.local"

# Encapsulation en mémoire des données de l'utilisateur dans les
# variables cortrespondantes

$msgID            = "Saisissez l'identifiant de l'utilisateur : "

$identifiant      = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::InputBox($msgID,"Identifiant")

if (Get-ADUser -F { SamAccountName -eq $identifiant }) 
{   
    # Si l'utilisateur existe, afficher un message d'alerte et mettre fin au script
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Le compte d'utilisateur $identifiant existe déjà dans l'AD.","Oups ! Un doublon...")
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Fin du script...","Fin du processus")
    Exit
}

# Création du formulaire de stockage des groupes de sécurité de l'AD
$frmGRP                    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$frmGRP.Text               = 'Selection de groupes'
$frmGRP.Size               = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,500)
$frmGRP.StartPosition      = 'CenterScreen'

$OKButton                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,430)
$OKButton.Size             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text             = 'OK'
$OKButton.DialogResult     = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

$frmGRP.AcceptButton       = $OKButton
$frmGRP.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,430)
$CancelButton.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text         = 'Abandonner'
$CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$frmGRP.CancelButton       = $CancelButton
$frmGRP.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$lblGRP                    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblGRP.Location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$lblGRP.Size               = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(480,20)
$lblGRP.Text               = 'Veuillez selectionner un ou plusieurs groupes...'
$frmGRP.Controls.Add($lblGRP)

$lstbGRP                   = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$lstbGRP.Location          = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$lstbGRP.Size              = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)

# Activation de la sélection multiples de groupes de sécurité
$lstbGRP.SelectionMode     = 'MultiExtended'

# Nom du fichier .csv des groupes de sécurité de l'AD
$fichierGRP = ".\ExportedGRP.csv"

if (Test-Path $fichierGRP)
{
  Remove-Item $fichierGRP
}

# Création dynamique de la liste des groupes de sécurité
Get-ADGroup -Filter '*' | Where-Object{ $_.objectclass -eq 'Group' } `
                        | Select-Object name `
                        | Sort-Object name `
                        | Export-Csv -encoding utf8 -Path $fichierGRP

(Get-Content $fichierGRP) -Replace '"', '' | Set-Content $fichierGRP

Get-Content $fichierGRP | ForEach-Object {[void] $lstbGRP.Items.Add($_)}

# Taille du champs d'affichage de la liste des groupes de sécurité
$lstbGRP.Height = 390
$frmGRP.Controls.Add($lstbGRP)
$frmGRP.Topmost = $true

# Affichage du formulaire des groupes de sécurité
$resultGRP = $frmGRP.ShowDialog()

# Sélection d'un groupe de sécurité pour l'utilisateur
if ($resultGRP -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $MembreDuGroupe = $lstbGRP.SelectedItems
}
else
{
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Fin du script...","Fin du processus")
    Exit
}

# Création du formulaires des OU
$frmOU                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$frmOU.Text                = 'Uniés Organisationnelles'
$frmOU.Size                = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,210)
$frmOU.StartPosition       = 'CenterScreen'

$lblOU                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblOU.Location            = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20)
$lblOU.Size                = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20)
$lblOU.Text                = 'Veuillez selectionner une ou plusieurs OU...'
$frmOU.Controls.Add($lblOU)

$lstbOU                    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Listbox
$lstbOU.Location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)
$lstbOU.Size               = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20)

$btnOU_OK                  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOU_OK.Location         = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,140)
$btnOU_OK.Size             = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$btnOU_OK.Text             = 'OK'
$btnOU_OK.DialogResult     = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

$btnOU_Cancel              = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$btnOU_Cancel.Location     = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,140)
$btnOU_Cancel.Size         = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$btnOU_Cancel.Text         = 'Abandonner'
$btnOU_Cancel.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel

$frmOU.CancelButton        = $btnOU_Cancel
$frmOU.Controls.Add($btnOU_Cancel)

$frmOU.AcceptButton        = $btnOU_OK
$frmOU.Controls.Add($btnOU_OK)

# Nom du fichier des OU au format .csv
$fichierOU = ".\ExportedOUs.csv"

# Remise à neuf du fichier -> Suppression du fichier, s'il existe
if (Test-Path $fichierOU) 
{
  Remove-Item $fichierOU
}

# Creation d'un fichier CSV pour stocker les OU
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * `
                         -Properties Name | Sort-Object Name `
                                          | Select-Object -Property DistinguishedName `
                                          | Export-Csv -encoding utf8 -Path $fichierOU

(Get-Content $fichierOU) -Replace '"', "'" | Set-Content $fichierOU

Get-Content $fichierOU | ForEach-Object {[void] $lstbOU.Items.Add($_)}

# Taille du champs d'affichage de la liste
$lstbOU.Height = 100
$frmOU.Controls.Add($lstbOU)
$frmOU.Topmost = $true

$resultOU = $frmOU.ShowDialog()

# Sélection d'un OU pour l'utilisateur
if ($resultOU -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
{
    $OU = ([string]$lstbOU.SelectedItem).Trim("'")
}
else
{
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Fin du script...","Fin du processus")
    Exit
}

# Enregistrement des données
try
{
    New-ADUser -Name $identifiant `
               -Path $OU `
               -SamAccountName $identifiant
        
    # #Affecter l'utilisateur à un groupe
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $MembreDuGroupe -Members  $identifiant

    # A la création de l'utilisateur, afficher un message d'information
    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("L'utilisateur $identifiant a été créé avec succès.","Création d'un utilisateur")
}
Catch
{
    # Affichage du message d'erreur
    # Récupération et affichage du message d'erreur dans son intégralité
    $formatstring = "{0} : {1}`n{2}`n" +
            "    + CategoryInfo          : {3}`n" +
            "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : {4}`n"
    $fields = $_.InvocationInfo.MyCommand.Name,
              $_.ErrorDetails.Message,
              $_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage,
              $_.CategoryInfo.ToString(),
              $_.FullyQualifiedErrorId

    # Pour afficher le message d'erreur dans la fenêtre PowerShell ISE
    # Supprimer le '#' avec la cmdlets ci-dessous : '$formatstring -f $fields'
    # $formatstring -f $fields

    $msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Une erreur est survenue lors de la création de l'utilisateur " + $identifiant + " " + $fields,"Oups ! Erreur lors du processus")
}

# Fin des traitements...
$msgBox =[System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("Fin de traitements...","Fin du processus")
```